# how to add labels in every docker remote build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rhel, docker-machine

I have a docker remote server to build all my images, now I need to add labels to every image build in the remote. I know that adding `--label label=value` works from local but when I call the remote docker I need to add specific labels to all image build in the remote docker.

In other words I want to add the OS version and the docker version to every image even if I call from local without any label in the command line

I want to do something like:

```
docker -H <remote-docker> build -f ./Dockerfile -t image:version
```

and when I do a `docker inspect` to the image stored in the remote docker the labels have:

```
Labels: {
    "os_version": 0.0.1,
    "docker_version": 1.17.0
}
```

Without I specify `--label` every time I build in remote docker.

Someone know how to add this labels in every build?